# confusion about character array initialisation

Tags: c, string, pointers

What is the difference between

```
   char ch [ ] = "hello";
```

and

```
   char ch [ ] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

and why we can only do

```
   char *p = "hello";
```

But cant do

```
   char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

Comment: Every string literal is also an array initializer, but obviously not every array initializer is a string literal. And the value of a string literal is a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two array declarations are the same. As for the pointer declaration, the form `char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};` is not valid, simply because it was not included in the compiler design.

There is no theoretical reason, in my knowledge, why that declaration should not be valid, when `char *p = "hello";` is.

Answer (score 3):

```
char ch [ ] = "hello";
char ch [ ] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

There is no difference. `ch` object will be exactly the same in both declarations.

On why we cannot do:

```
char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

An initializer list of more than one value can only be used for objects of aggregate type (structures or array). You can only initialize a `char *` with a pointer value.

Actually:

```
char ch [ ] = "hello";
```

and

```
char *p = "hello";
```

are not the same. The first initializes an array with the elements of a string literal and the second is a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: For the same reason you can't do `int *p = {1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: Strings are a special case where you _can_ initialize a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Suddenly¹: `int *p = (int[]){ 1, 2, 3 };`, but that's something different. (¹: c99)

Answer (score 1):

Open upon a time they made a mistake about `const`

The bit "hello" should be a `const char * const` but they where lazy and just used `char *`. But to keep the faith alive they let that one slip.

Then they said. Ok. They can be equal.

Then they had `char [] = { 'a', 'b', ...};` and all was good in the world

The the evil monster came and thrust upon them `char *p = "hello"`. But the evil monster was in a good mood and said it should be `const char *p = "hello"` but I would be happy with that.

He went home and but the evil monster was not amused. He dictated over his realm `char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};` is the sign of a heretic.

Basically there was a cock-up. Just do it right from now and there is old code kicking around that needs to be satisfied.

Comment: Amusing but you could give it more syntactical love. Just saying

Comment: @ThunderGr - Get a +1 for finding it amusing.

Comment: Well, for a +1, it should actually be helpful to someone not familiar with the story you are telling. And I'm afraid that it does not clarify anything to someone trying to learn C. So, no upvote from me either.

Comment: why `const char * const`? The pointer itself doesn't have to be constant, but only the object it points to.

Comment: @ajay- it does not have to be constant but it can be. If the pointer is constant the compiler could optimize if a bit

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it one by one. This following is initializing a `char` **array** `ch` using the string literal `"hello"`.

```
char ch[] = "hello";
```

The following is initializing the **array** `ch` using an array initialization list. This is equivalent to the above statement.

```
char ch[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

The following is initializing a `char` **pointer** `p` to point to the memory where the string literal `"hello"` is stored. This is read-only memory. Attempting to modify its contents will not give compile error because string literal in `C` are not const qualified unlike in `C++`, but will cause undefined behaviour or even program crash.

```
char *p = "hello";
const char *p = "hello";  // better
```

The following last statement is plain wrong.

```
char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

`p` is a `char` pointer here, not an array and can't be initialized using array initialization list. I have highlighted the words `array` and `pointer` above to emphasize that array and pointer are different types. In some cases, an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element like when an array is passed to a function or assigned to a pointer of the same type. This does not mean they are the same. They have different pointer arithmetic and different `sizeof` values.

Comment: "hello" is an array, as well, and we use char* p with no problem. The explanation is lacking, in my opinion

Comment: `"hello"` is a string literal, not an array in the strictest sense of the terms. `char` arrays don't need to be null terminated but strings, by definition, are null terminated

Comment: It is a string literal, which is an array of chars. So, it looks like an array in the strictest sense.

Comment: @ThunderGr string literal is an array of chars but it always contains a null byte at the end. A char array doesn't have to contain a null byte. If it does, then we can call it a string.

Comment: a `char* p`, is not required to point to a null-terminated array of chars. You can declare `char[] some={'h','i'};` and then do a `char* p=&some[0];`

Comment: Both of you are confusing the terms. `"hello"` is a string literal, not an array, not a string, not a `char*` or anything, it is a string literal. How it is used, depends on the context. In the context of an array initialization, it behaves like an initializer list, in the context of a pointer initialization, it behaves like a pointer to static data. It can only do that because it is neither.

Comment: @cmaster right! I never said a string literal is an array.

Comment: @cmaster static data that form an array of bytes. I do not think we are that confused. I think we both know the way the data are in memory and what an array actually is in memory terms. The memory structure is the same in both instances

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference in

```
char ch [ ] = "hello";
char ch [ ] = { 'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

But check below

```
char *p = "hello";  //This is correct

char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};  //This is wrong
```

If you want to make it correct you need to use

```
char *p[]={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}; //This works
```

Comment: Then *p[] would become array of pointers i dont wana use this but i wana ask why char *p cant do that?

Comment: `char *p[]={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};` this is wrong and any compiler has the right to refuse it. You declare an array of `char *` but your elements are `char`.

Comment: For the sake of programming char *p[]={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
This syntax is absolutely correct we can define char *p[] 
there is no mistake